# Missing Organization Feature: Chatter

Tags: apex, chatter

We created a package that uses chatter functionality. One of our users is not using chatter and disabled in their org so our package is throwing an error "Missing Organization Feature: Chatter". User is not willing to enable chatter.

Is there a way that we can write some condition if chatter is enabled do this and if not do this.

I am already checking id the chatter is enabled using the below snippet

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = CSTest__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
            return R.isFeedEnabled();
```

In visualforce page

```
<chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!testIdChatter}" id="chatterId" />
```

Is there away that we can write the functionality if the chatter is not enabled do some other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is a hard problem without many tried and tested solutions!

**Determining if chatter is enabled:**

```
Boolean isChatterEnabled = true;
try {Type.forName('FeedItem');}
catch (System.NoAccessException e) {isChatterEnabled = false;}

System.debug(isChatterEnabled);
//gives true/false as appropriate
```

**Possible prevention of feature dependency in Visualforce:**

```
<!-- try using a Dynamic Component in the VF page -->
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!DynamicChatter}" />

//this is all a wild guess
public ApexPages.Component getDynamicChatter() {
    ApexPages.Component cmp;
    if (isChatterEnabled) {
        ApexPages.Component cmp = Type.forName('Component.Apex.Chatter').newInstance();
        cmp.put('entityId', testIdChatter);
        cmp.put('id', 'chatterId');
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

**Prevention of feature dependency when performing DML using dynamic types for inserts:**

```
public 
if (isChatterEnabled) {
    SObject feedItem = Type.forName('FeedItem');
    feedItem.put('ParentId', UserInfo.getUserId());
    feedItem.put('Body', 'Check out my dependency free chatter post!');
    insert feedItem;
}
```

**Prevention of feature dependency when querying, using dynamic SOQL:**

```
if (isChatterEnabled) {
    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    List<SObject> myPosts = Database.query('SELECT Body FROM FeedItem WHERE Id = :userId');
}
```

Comment: I am keeping the condition where ever we are querying feed object and if chatter is enabled then only do this. I don't where the dependency got introduced and need to check line by line.

Comment: I raised support ticket to salesforce Their Answer is "As mentioned in the error message, we cannot install packages which include chatter functionality in orgs which do not have chatter enabled. 

Please let me know your further queries on this case."

Comment: @UgeshGali totally worth educating your customer on the benefits of Chatter, if your app requires it. It's an ever-growing cost trying to tip-toe around the feature dependency for the sake of these holdouts ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This specific situation is addressed in the documentation for ISV apps. It references the error and where you must do a specific try-catch to get around it. 
I think the document is called ISVForce documentation. It is the one that also has instructions for LMA and best practices for working with managed packages.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the connect api for this. There is a method [getSettings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_Organization_static_methods.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=Chatter%7Cchatter%7C%7Cenables%7Cenable%7Cenabled%7CEnable%7Cenabling%7CEnabled%7CENABLED%7CEnables#apex_ConnectAPI_Organization_getSettings) that returns which features are enabled

```
ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings().features.chatter
```